# Can I send programatically generated text as a Mailgun attachment using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, attachment, mailgun

The examples from the [Mailgun documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#sending-via-api) show how to send an attachment specified by a filename. Is it possible to send a dynamically generated string?

Something like the following:

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("from", "me@me.com");
form.append("to", "you@you.com");
form.append("subject", "Email Subject");
form.append("text", "Email body");
form.append("attachment", "Attachment text content", "attachment.txt");

//POST form…
```

Using this code the attachment is ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this using a blob:

```
var file = new Blob(["Attachment text content"], {type: "text/plain"});
form.append("attachment", file, "attachment.txt");
```